# The best representation for duration between dates in rest api

Tags: rest, date, datetime, software-design, time-format

I'm implementing a rest API to repent some business stuff. One of the elements to return is the duration of some operations, represented by a specific time. I am wondering: what are the most common ways to represent that kind of data? Currently, I am trying to use ISO 8601 duration, but maybe this is not the best format for some reasons?

```
{
  ...
  "averageDuration": "PT9.705S"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Without context it is hard to tell, but milliseconds almost always fit in these scenarios, unless it is a very big duration. `{ "averageDuration": 14000 }` -- 14,000 milliseconds

Comment: What implementation detail makes you think ISO 8601 duration might not be a good fit?